# Why can not find the server route of an express server from react native when trying to upload a file?

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, fetch, multer

i have configured an express server that use multer as a middleware in order to upload images to GCS, it works as expected and wanted when making the respective request from insomnia, but when trying to do it from my project in react native, i can not even get connected to that route, and actually i do not know the reason and what else to try.
this is the code from the server:

```
const storage =
    multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, 'uploads/')
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
        }
    })

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
app.listen(3000);
app.use(router)

router.post('/uploadImage', upload.single('file'), async function (req, res) {
    console.log("se conectaron a /uploadingImage")...
```

**This is code from the frontend in react native:**

```
_pickImage = async () => {
        this.getPermissionAsync()
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
        });
        state = {
            search: '',
        };
        this.uploadImage(`http://192.168.1.69:3000/uploadImage`, {
            file: {
                height:result.height,
                type: result.type,
                uri: result.uri,
                width: result.width,
            }
        }).then(r => {

        });
        if (!result.cancelled) {
            this.setState({ image: result.uri });
        }
    };

    async uploadImage(url, data) {
        let options = {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            method: 'POST'
        }
        options.body = new FormData();
        for (let key in data) {
            options.body.append(key, data[key]);
        }
        return fetch(url, options)
            .then(async response => {
                return response.json()
                    .then(responseJson => {
                        return responseJson;
                    });
            });
    }
```

*My server have never log in the console the first line in the route ("se conectaron a /uploadingImage")*

Comment: To be hones I could not find the problem, but while the console.log is not executed then the middleware you make upload.single is surely not working properly or not allowing the request to pass it. Try checking if the image is reaching the server or not.

Comment: @LouayAlosh Actually it seems that the server is not reached because the first line inside of it is never printed, the others routes are reached, but do not use multer... it may be the cause, but i do not why...

Comment: okay I think that multer didn't allow the pipe of execution to continue to the next middleware function which is wired here.. I searched for such thing and I found this https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/325